# Is Xpack mandatory for cross cluster search with encryption

Tags: elasticsearch, encryption, truststore, elasticsearch-x-pack, search-guard

I have a OSS elasticsearch with SearchGuard plugin for HTTP and transport encryption in single cluster.

I want to be able to do a cross cluster search across two such cluster.

Is X-pack mandatory (to create that user / role) to search across local and remote cluster?

Is there a way to work around it? I just need the ES cluster to be able to do cross cluster search with encrypted transport. I don't need user roles.

Comment: Did you ever get the answer to this?

Comment: I figured that its not mandatory.  1) I used search gaurd SSL encryption for transport layer. 2) Made sure that  either same certs are used for both cluster for SSL encryption
OR you cross import the certificates. 3) Configure cross cluster search using seed node.